# How to follow someone at Gwibber for Twitter

Tags: gwibber

I have added my Twitter account in Gwibber and the timeline is showing correctly.

I would like to know, how can I follow someone through Gwibber. For example in Hotot, I can click on the icon and then click on "Follow".

May be there is a way to do that in Gwibber also but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function.

You have to click on 'view this message', which opens a web page of the message where you can then switch to the user-profile.

Comment: That means the feature (Follow someone from the timeline), is not yet been added. Thanks for your response.

Comment: There are actually some confirmed bugs/feature requests regarding this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/gwibber/+bug/519262. I guess it will be implemented in the near future